# Have installed Ubuntu but when I restart computer, it only goes to 'grub'...Ubuntu doesn't load?

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu (without Windows) and done a restart.  Ubuntu doesn't load...all I get is grub> and don't know how to get beyond it.

Can you help

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to recover your grub installation with a live cd?

my source is https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#Recover

but i personally tried it works

This method of installation uses the chroot command to gain access to the broken system's files. Once the chroot command is issued, the LiveCD treats the broken system's / as its own. Commands run in a chroot environment will affect the broken systems filesystems and not those of the LiveCD.

1) Boot to the LiveCD Desktop (Ubuntu 9.10 or later). Please note that the Live CD must be the same as the system you are fixing - either 32-bit or 64-bit (if not then the chroot will fail).

2) Open a terminal - Applications, Accessories, Terminal. 3) Determine your normal system partition - (the switch is a lowercase "L")

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you aren't sure, run

```
df -Th
```

Look for the correct disk size and ext3 or ext4 format.

4) Mount your normal system partition:
Substitute the correct partition: sda1, sdb5, etc.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt  

# Example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

5) Only if you have a separate boot partition: sdYY is the /boot partition designation (for example sdb3)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot
```

6) Mount the critical virtual filesystems:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
```

7) Chroot into your normal system device:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

8) If there is no /boot/grub/grub.cfg or it's not correct, create one using

```
update-grub
```

9) Reinstall GRUB 2:

Substitute the correct device - sda, sdb, etc. Do not specify a partition number.

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
```

10) Verify the install (use the correct device, for example sda. Do not specify a partition):

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

11) Exit chroot: CTRL-D on keyboard

12) Unmount virtual filesystems:

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
```

13) If you mounted a separate /boot partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/boot
```

14) Unmount the LiveCD's /usr directory:

```
sudo umount /mnt/usr
```

15) Unmount last device:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

16) Reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

hope it will work